# AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Tags: list

I have a mistake that I can't solve.. have you got an advice?

```
polygons = [r['shape_attributes'] for r in a['regions'].values()]
```

> AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'values'

Comment: I use `a.get('regions')`, maybe it's better ? Because I'm using a dict .

Comment: Please specify programming language you're using in tags

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well : `a` is a dictionnary but `a['regions']` is a list of dictionnaries.

Indeed a 'list' object has no attribute 'values'.
If you want to loop over the values of your list you need to use this syntax :

```
polygons = [region['shape_attributes'] for region in a['regions']]
```

Comment: Yes exactly but If I use it, we get this error : `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: Maybe it would help if you described precisely what is a['regions']

Comment: it's like this : `{ 'filename': '28503151_5b5b7ec140_b.jpg',
           'regions': {
               '0': {
                   'region_attributes': {},
                   'shape_attributes': {
                       'all_points_x': [...],
                       'all_points_y': [...],
                       'name': 'polygon'}},
               ... more regions ...
           },
           'size': 100202
         }`

Comment: Can you try :
polygons = [value['shape_attributes'] for key, value in a['regions'].items()]

Comment: hi no! `AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'items'`

Comment: a['regions'] appears to be a list, but you describe it as a dictionnary so something is incoherent but I don't know what

Comment: I edited my answer, assuming that in your second comment you meant `'regions': [...]` instead of `'regions': {...}`

Answer (score 0):

you need for each annotation-img one dictionary, that's the way **Mask RCNN** works.

```
{
    "IMG_20180413_091455.jpg1231831": {
        "base64_img_data": "",
        "file_attributes": {},
        "filename": "IMG_20180413_091455.jpg",
        "fileref": "",
        "regions": {
            "0": {
                "region_attributes": {
                    "damage": "damage"
                },
                "shape_attributes": {
                    "all_points_x": [
                        2388,
                        2586,
                        2645,
                        2655,
                        2635,
                        2497,
                        2363,
                        2328,
                        2388
                    ],
                    "all_points_y": [
                        1100,
                        1129,
                        1189,
                        1243,
                        1298,
                        1298,
                        1229,
                        1159,
                        1100
                    ],
                    "name": "polygon"
                }
            }
        },
        "size": 1231831
    },
```

you need to add your load_funcion and your json file, Otherwise it's hard to help you.

I really want to know the result if you print this line.

```
annotations = list(annotations1.values())
```